# javascript promises return

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

I have a function `func` which resolves a promise and then tries to return the updated value of a local variable `returnval`

```
func: function(){
   returnval = false;
   var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
       // some stuff .. 
       returnval = true;
       resolve();
   });
   promise.then(function(){
       return returnval;
   });
}
```

I guess the `return returnval` returns from the promise object. How do I return the updated value of `returnval` from the `func` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ef4btxnv/

Answer (score -1):

To have the function return:

```
func: function(){
   returnval = false;
   var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
       // some stuff .. 
       returnval = true;
       resolve();
   });
   promise.then(function(){
       return returnval;
   });
   return returnval; //this will return from the function call
}
```